# Where should I put the "/login" route in api.php or web.php?

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

I use laravel/sanctum to authenticate my spa. I also use postman.
And the problem is in different behaviors in postman and with requests from the browser(vue,axios).
I am completely confused in the correct implementation of authorization.

Laravel sanctum spa authentication docs: `Once CSRF protection has been initialized, you should make a POST request to your Laravel application's /login route. This /login route may be implemented manually or using a headless authentication package like Laravel Fortify.`

In postman I use all needed headers like X-XSRF-TOKEN in login request and Referer in other request on protected routes.

My authentication logic: `return Auth::attempt($authorizationData->toArray());`.

When I place my login route in web.php it works fine in postman:

`Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->middleware('web');`

But when I place this in api.php i can login but i cant pass auth:sanctum in postman:

`Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->group(function () {`
I receive:

```
{
    "message": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

But also when I try to do it not with the postman but with the axios, and place routes in api.php I can pass auth:sanctum, but in this case, everything works without "/sanctum/csrf-cookie" request:

> To authenticate your SPA, your SPA's "login" page should first make a request to the /sanctum/csrf-cookie endpoint to initialize CSRF protection for the application:
>
> ```
> axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
> Login...
> });
> ```

.